# How can I separate a data that I have broken as a key value again according to the -> sign?

Tags: java, spring, split, java-8, key-value

If there is a `->` sign, I want to separate the data that I have broken as a key value and take the left part as key and the remaining part as value. How can I shred `favoriteInterestKeys`?

```java
List<Rule> favoriteInterests = ruleMap.values().stream()
    .filter(rule -> keys.contains(rule.getSolrName()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

```
example data : citizienship_s -> Türkiye
Key : citizenship_s
Value : Türkiye
Value : 3.0
Key : tv_interest_f 
Value : 3.0 
Key : entertainment_interest_f
Value : 3.0
```

How can I allocate key-value for `citizienship_s` here?`

[image]

Comment: It is not quite clear what you try to achieve.  Currently you seem to have a `Map<String, String>`, where _some_ keys _should_ be split into another key-value pair, so that this map has to be converted into `Map<Pair<String, String>, String>`/`Map<Map.Entry<String, String>, String>`